# autoencoder reconstructed image (output) are not clear as i want

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am using an autoencoder,Is that okey if reconstructed image are like this because the input image has lost a lot of quality
[reconstructed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wK8I.png)

what should i do to have an image that looks more like the input because ,i will use the output image for face recognition.

should i edit epochs,batch size ..?.

Comment: Yes, auto-encoders with a pixel reconstruction loss tend to produce blurry images. This subject of research is way more than what can be covered in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks for reply , yes that's true..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the go-to ways to improve performance is to change the learning rate. You can do this by creating your own [optimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/) with a different learning rate. The RMSProp optimizer defaults to a learning rate of 0.001. If your images are in [0, 1] then I suggest trying a higher learning rate, maybe 0.1. If they are in [0, 255], maybe 0.0001. Experiment!

Another issue might be that you have too many max pooling layers in the encoder, decimating spatial information. When I use max pooling, I try to keep it at less than 1 pooling layer per 2 convolutional layers. You could replace the max pooling with stride 2 convolutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer  I will try to edit the code, how about curve Roc can i add it to my code .

Comment: In machine learning, it's more common to use a [validation curve](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7). This is where you put a portion of your data aside, e.g..20%,  for evaluating the model's performance. You can evaluate the model every few training iterations e.g. every 10 iterations. Validation helps detect overfitting and measure expected performance on unseen examples. You should also have a test set to evaluate your final model.

Comment: for an rgb images we need higher or lower learning rate what you mean by [0,255]

Comment: @GuizmoCharo Image pixels in the range [0,255] instead of [0,1]